# iPod Click Wheel Games disappeared from iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, games, ipod-classic

Is it still possible to buy iPod Click Wheel Games for the iPod Classic? I can't find them on iTunes. Is there a way to side-load them and get them from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

They've been gone for a while. I don't remember exactly when, but it was more than a year ago. There's no way to buy them anywhere else.